# heard a nightingale singing vs small girl standing?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, meaning, adjectives, relative-clauses

> **Have you ever heard a nightingale singing ?** **I saw a small girl standing in the goldfish pond.**

How do we think of the words 'singing and standing' in this sentences?

Adjective or progressive ?

Comment: Sites, such as this one, on participles, will help to answer your questions: https://www.thesaurus.com/e/grammar/whats-a-participle/

Comment: Neither: they are both verbs heading gerund-participial clauses.

Answer (score 1):

> *Have you ever heard a nightingale*] [*singing*]*?*
>
> *I saw a small girl* [*standing in the goldfish pond*].

"Singing" and "standing" are not adjectives but verbs, more precisely gerund-participle verbs.

These are complex catenative constructions, where the gerund-participial clauses (bracketed) are complements of the verbs "hear" and "see".

The clauses have a progressive meaning, but they do not have progressive aspectuality since the verb "be" is not present. Compare the present progressive aspect in "A nightingale *was singing*".

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, does it matter? From a practical point of view.  Would your understanding be different?  Is there a case in which you would answer "Yes I have heard a nightingale singing(participle) and No, I haven't heard a nightingale singing(adjective)." ?

Theoretically, particles are a form of a verb, and have a subject (which may be implied). Here there is a subject for "singing", it is "nightingale". Likewise there is a subject for "standing" (it is a "little girl") As these words have subjects, they must be verbs, and therefore -ing participles.

Now -ing participles are used to form the progressive, and they do have a progressive sense in these sentences.  You could paraphrase with a relative clause with a progressive verb "a nightingale that was singing".  The progressive is formed from a "be" verb and the -ing participle.

Comment: sometimes there are differences in understanding.  What I really want to know is how can we differentiate this? for example : We discovered the tortoise ambling out of the gate. They caught Mary stealing from the bank

Comment: Well if you really want to know about that you should ask a question about it.  But in both cases, can you identify a subject for the word "ambling" or "stealing".  If so, it's probably a participle. On the other hand if you can say "very ....ing" or "more ...ing" it is likely to be an adjective.